# deprecated struct members C++

Tags: c++, gcc

GCC 6.1.1 gives me a deprecated declaration warning on the C++ code

```
struct foo
{
   __attribute__ ((deprecated)) static const int a = 1;
};


dep.cpp:1:8: warning: ‘foo::a’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   struct foo
          ^~~
dep.cpp:3:50: note: declared here
   __attribute__ ((deprecated)) static const int a = 1;
```

The [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.1.0/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bdeprecated_007d-variable-attribute-3491) says that "The deprecated attribute results in a warning if the variable is used anywhere in the source file.".

As the warning points to the first line (struct foo), does that mean that the warning is raised because the struct is "using" the deprecated member?
Is there a way to use the deprecated attribute for static const struct members?

GCC 4.9.3 does not seem to give this warning.

Comment: Probably a compiler bug -- gcc is likely getting confused by the "= 1" part, and interprets it as usage.

Comment: @M.M: have you tried it in `clang++` ?

Comment: clang 3.8.0 does not raise this warning.

Comment: Too much off an hassle to go to windows. I'll try it with the GCC bugtracker then.

Comment: GNU C version 4.9.2 brings better in your sense:
***.cpp:7:8: warning: 'foo::a' is deprecated (declared at ***.cpp:3) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   foo::a =2;

Comment: Even without the = 1, the warning comes up. I've submitted this to the [GCC bugtracker](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71274)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is a bug of GCC >= 5.0 (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71274).